# How to send SMS through "USB" connected mobiles?

Tags: vb.net

I am not a professional developer but I want to develop one project that includes sending message through mobile connected through USB port only... And if possible I want to keep it generalized, like no need for handset model and service provider name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do this. Certainly at the very least it would depend on the model of mobile in use.
However as an alternative approach there are companies that provide a (paid for, but not expensive) SMS service accessible via a web API. This may suit what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: for sure, this is *definitely* something that be phone model specific.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find this easy. Messages can be sent in 2 different modes 'text' or PDU. Support for both modes is not universal across all phones. PDU is the most widely available type on modern phones, but is also the most complex. Not all mobile phones expose a modem to the computer eg. Windows mobile 6.*. Many phones use proprietory software that does not support all commands. Different phones will connect to different COM ports so this will need checking every time, and could prove tricky if there is more than one phone/modem connected. However using just one phone and sending messages in text format after configuring the settings manually the first time is very easy.

See an example here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34360/vb-net-AT-commands-to-send-SMS